# Error due to different version of firebase dependencies. How to use different versions of those dependencies?

Tags: firebase, android-studio, firebase-storage

This is kind of a weird error. In my app I was uploading images to firebase storage and retrieving them.All my firebase dependencies were of **version 11.8.0**.  It worked fine until I added firebase auth v11.8.0.

I couldn't use auth with dependency v-11.8.0 so **I changed all dependencies to v-16.0.1.** Now auth works fine but I can't use **tasksnapshot.getDownloadUrl()** since it's deprecated and no longer supported by the version 16.0.1 storage dependency.But I want to use it so I kept all other versions as 16.0.1 and changed firebase storage to v-11.8.0 back again. Now this is the error I'm getting

> java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: The method 'boolean com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzb()' was expected to be of type virtual but instead was found to be of type direct (declaration of 'java.lang.reflect.ArtMethod' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)

I got these weird kind of errors 'zzb()' in my previous apps when the dependencies had different versions. So in short how can I use different versions of those dependencies? ***How can I use firebase-storage version 11.8.0 and others with version 16.0.1?***

Comment: You should use `StorageReference.getDownloadUrl()` instead.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference.html#getDownloadUrl()

Comment: I guess, but I was wondering if I could do it the way it's in the question.

Comment: My comment strongly suggests your course of action.